# Use pluck in Active Model Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I would like to use pluck method in Active Model Serializer for an object association:

```
Post has_many :comments
```

Is there a way to override

```
 has_many :comments
```

in the serializer to use pluck(:id, :title) on the comments ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use block with has_many to extend your association with methods. See comment "Use a block to extend your associations" [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many#461-User-a-block-to-extend-your-associations).

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments do
     def plucked()
       select("id, title")
     end
   end
end
```

or other approach, from the same link can be, have your custom sql query when fetching `comments` from the database:

```
has_many :comments, :class_name => 'Comment', :finder_sql => %q(
  SELECT id, title
  FROM comments
  WHERE post_id = #{id}
)
```

In rails [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.1.3/association_basics.html#options-for-has_many), It shows, there is an option `:select`, which can also be used for this purpose.

Comment: Isnt't that the same as setting the attributes in the comments serializer? I want to use pluck on the associated comments because it's faster than having active record serializing the comment object

Comment: Can you state what is your end goal, what you want to achieve here, by giving some example.

Comment: The goal is to fetch associated objects with the Parent. In that case fetch the comments with the Post. But since there a lot of comments, try to make the query as fast as possible by using pluck on the associated comments in the serializer.

Comment: Hi @stefano_cdn, updated my answer, Please try them out. I haven't run those, so sorry if there is some syntactical mistake.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do in that situation, I have two different serializers `CommentSerializer` and `CommentInfoSerializer`. So `CommentInfoSerializer` only includes minimum attributes that I want to response in embedded attribute of their parent resource.

```
class CommentSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body
end

class CommentInfoSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title
end

class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  has_many :comments, serializer: CommentInfoSerializer
end
```